# Effective configuration of dkimproxy in multiple-domain scenario

Tags: postfix, dkim

I have a postfix/dkimproxy setup that doesn't work the way I like.

I have `exampledomain.org` with SPF allowing mail only from `server.exampledomain.org` (rDNS mapped correctly) which is also aliased by `smtp.exampledomain.org`.

Currently, web applications running on the server use Postfix's builtin `sendmail` command when sending outbound emails. These emails come from `wwwrun@server.exampledomain.org` and they are properly DKIM-signed. That is correct!

When a user with `@exampledomain.org` (me!!) sends mail from Outlook it connects to `smtp.exampledomain.org` and authenticates after `STARTTLS` command. Unfortunately, emails are not DKIM signed. Logs show that the email is automatically relayed and doesn't go through `dkimproxy`. dkimproxy is configured as follows

```
# specify what address/port DKIMproxy should listen on
listen    127.0.0.1:10027

# specify what address/port DKIMproxy forwards mail to
relay     127.0.0.1:10028

# specify what domains DKIMproxy can sign for (comma-separated, no spaces)
domain    server.exampledomain.org,exampledomain.org

# specify what signatures to add
signature dkim(c=simple)
signature domainkeys(c=nofws)

# specify location of the private key
keyfile   /etc/ssl/private/dkim_server/dkim_server.key


# specify the selector (i.e. the name of the key record put in DNS)
selector  server
```

DNS TXT records are already set.

Postfix is configured with a large master.cf file that I won't paste in its entirety. The relevant lines are

```
#
# modify the default submission service to specify a content filter
# and restrict it to local clients and SASL authenticated clients only
#
submission  inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_etrn_restrictions=reject
    -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
    -o content_filter=dksign:[127.0.0.1]:10027
    -o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject

#
# specify the location of the DomainKeys signing filter
#
dksign    unix  -       -       n       -       10      smtp
    -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
    -o smtp_discard_ehlo_keywords=8bitmime,starttls

#
# service for accepting messages FROM the DomainKeys signing filter
#
127.0.0.1:10028 inet  n  -      n       -       10      smtpd
    -o content_filter=
    -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
    -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
    -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
    -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
```

#### The question is

Why doesn't mail coming from the external get processed by dkimproxy?

Comment: That configuration looks correct. Are you sure that Outlook is connecting on port 587 to send mail (instead of 25)?

Comment: Outlook is connecting to 25. That is default value. What's wrong with 25?

Comment: Switching to 587 did work! But question above is still active because I would like to understand. If you could answer the question I'll upvote and accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that Outlook is connecting to the submission port (port 587), instead of port 25. This is because the Postfix configuration works by signing mail received on port 587 (i.e. from your clients sending outgoing mail), but not mail received on port 25 (because this is mail being delivered to your server by other MTAs). This is implemented by the `content_filter` line in `main.cf`, which you'll note is present in the `submission inet` definition, but not the `smtp inet` definition.